# How do I get the Texture/Material to be attached to the model when exporting the file as fbx?

Tags: texturing, materials

How do I get the Texture to be attached to the object when exporting the file as fbx? I tried searching many ways on YouTube but couldn't find any solution. If anyone knows please help me. Thanks.
My file  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SQ4WrI0WVhHqKR3JvOqOIt4VZbuXi4XD/view?usp=drive_link
[image]

I use this method where some objects can have textures or materials attached to them, but the object I'm working on currently can't.[image] When I import file fbx the result is that my object does not have a Texture [image]
Or when I save an image, but it doesn't show the entire texture or material.
[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures  In any case the link you've provided requires you to grant access so the file is only available to you at the moment.

Comment: sorry I forgot, now everyone has access.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SQ4WrI0WVhHqKR3JvOqOIt4VZbuXi4XD/view?usp=drive_link

Comment: As suspected, your material contains more nodes than just the Principled BSDF shader which can't be exported from Blender. You don't say what you're importing your fbx file into, but read the "How to solve it then?" section at the bottom of the question I pointed you at to see how you can get round the problem.

Comment: How to fix it? sir

Comment: You can't "fix it" because the fbx file format simply doesn't support the use of Blender's texture nodes apart from just the Principled BSDF node on its own.  As I said in my last comment, read the "How to solve it" section at the end of https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures.